# Read text file with scanner and insert line break every 10 characters

Tags: java, text, java.util.scanner

Having trouble with a java exercise, I need to take input from a text file and print the contents out but insert a new line break every 10 characters, for example it should read in:
I like to eat ice cream

as

I like to 
eat ice cr
eam

heres my current solution so far

```
public class practice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner (practice.class.getResourceAsStream("hello.txt"));
String currentLine = "";
String lineTen = "\n";
int charCount = 0;

while (input.hasNext()) {
    currentLine =  input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(currentLine);
    //charCount++;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentLine.length(); i++) {
        if (currentLine.charAt(i) !=  ' ' && currentLine.charAt(i) != '\n') 
        {
            charCount++;
        }
        if (charCount > 20) {
        currentLine = ("\n");
        }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(currentLine);
    System.out.println(charCount);
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `currentLine = ("\n");` sets the whole line equal to a new line, so any string longer than 20 characters will just print out as a new line. Also in your question you said 10 characters, but your code counts to 20 characters. You aren't resetting charCount either so as soon as 20 characters are reached every character after that will trigger the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Why are you excluding spaces if you are counting them in the example? you should remove that in the code, you can building a string then print it when its complete as the following:

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) {
        String currentLine = "";
        String result = "";
        int charCount = 0;
        while (input.hasNext())
            currentLine += input.nextLine() + " ";
            //charCount++;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentLine.length(); i++) {
            if (currentLine.charAt(i) != '\n') { 
                if (charCount >= 20) {
                    result+= "\n" + currentLine.charAt(i);
                    charCount = 1;
                }
                else {
                    result += currentLine.charAt(i);
                    charCount++;
                }
            }
            else
                charCount++;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

also use `try-with-resources` as shown in the code above.

input:

```
I like to eat ice cream
```

output:

```
I like to eat ice cre
am
```